# How can I code to find the highest since ma crossover

Tags: pine-script

How can I code to return the highest price since the Moving Average Crossover, and so do the lowest price since the moving average crossunder?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `var` variable to keep track of the price. Reset this when there is a crossover or crossunder.

```
var float highest_high = na

if (sma_crossover)            // Check for crossover
    highest_high := high      // Reset your variable
else
    if (high > highest_high)
        highest_high := high  // Update the highest high
```